# Push from local repo to origin. Origin being another local copy of repo on different machine

Tags: git

In what might be a typical scenario, your repo is hosted on a remote server. Your remote code may then be tracked by a local client.

In this scenario, I'm curious to know if the local client can itself act as a serving entity to another local client?

And can you chain that so that several clients are involved?

So in this chain

- LocalA > push > LocalB > push > Remote

This relationship would be defined as

- LocalA(client) > LocalB(**server**)

And this relationship would be defined as

- LocalB(client) > Remote(**server**)

Comment: Push To local B and Link LocalB(client) with Remote server for example If you are using hostinger server view this link https://support.hostinger.com/en/articles/1583302-how-can-i-deploy-a-git-repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you push from Repo A to Repo B, Repo A is acting as a client and B as a server.

When you fetch from Repo A to Repo B, Repo A is acting as a server and B as a client.

Specially, when you fetch/push from Repo A to Repo A itself, Repo A is acting as both a client and a server. For example, in Repo A, you can run `git push . HEAD:new_branch` or `git fetch . HEAD:new_branch`. Both create a new branch from `HEAD`.

Repo A and Repo B can be on the same machine, or on different machines, as long as one can access to the other.